# send data from select tag to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a simple select tag

```
Job Category:
    <select name="jobCat">
        <option value="tech">Technology</option>
        <option value="admin">Administration</option>
        <option value="biology">Biology</option>
        <option value="science">Science</option>
     </select>
```

now when the user selects a option i want to send the data to a servlet dopost method?

The above code resides in abc.jsp and the name of servlet file is pqr.java

How to perform the above action?

I have read something like

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    UserId  <input type="text/html" name="userId"/><br><br>
    Password <input type="password" name="password"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and this i mapped to login servlet by

```
WebServlet("/login")
```

so when the user presses submit then the data is sent to this servlet. Now i want to achieve the same functionality with the select statement?

This is the scheduleMeet.jsp file
`    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="important.businessService.dto.Employee" %>
    
    
    
    
    Insert title here

```
</head>
<body>

Job Category:
<form action="scheduleMeet" method="post">
<select name="jobCat">
    <option value="tech">Technology</option>
    <option value="admin">Administration</option>
    <option value="biology">Biology</option>
    <option value="science">Science</option>
</select>
</form>


</body>
</html>`
```

and this is the  ScheduleMeetServlet.java
`    package important;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class scheduleMeetServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/scheduleMeet")
public class scheduleMeetServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String jobCategory = request.getParameter("jobCat");
    System.out.println("Job category is: " + jobCategory);
}
}
```

`

Comment: You'll need a little javascript

Comment: where is the submit button in jsp form for schedule meet?

Comment: use servlet name in the action of your form scheduleMeetServlet

Comment: @kirti No that is not required , he can use any `url` and only it needs to be mapped in the sevlet. i guess his servlet might be inside some package and not visible to the form. so try to use `./scheduleMeet` in the form action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using name of the select

Your select must be inside the form

```
<form action="login" method="post">
<select name="jobCat">
        <option value="tech">Technology</option>
        <option value="admin">Administration</option>
        <option value="biology">Biology</option>
        <option value="science">Science</option>
     </select>

 UserId <input type="text/html" name="userId"/><br><br> Password <input type="password" name="password"/><br><br> <input type="submit"/> </form>
```

In your Login servlet, 
in your servlet post method just use the request.getparameter to get that value

```
eg



  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        String selectedvalue  =  request.getparameter("jobCat");
         // you will get that value in the string selectedvalue
        }
```

Comment: I have not done javascript can u give me a snippit if it is not a problem and how to define the url mapping with annotation

Comment: it doesnt require any javascript code , the same code `String selectedvalue  =  request.getparameter("jobCat");` will work

Comment: @kirit check the name of the select in your answer ? should be `jobCat`

Comment: yes i checked the name and just cant figure out what to put in 

@WebServlet("            ")

Comment: you need to map the url patter given in your `<form action` attribute . in your case `WebServlet("/login")` is enough

Comment: i did this 
`
@WebServlet("/schedule")
public class scheduleMeetServlet extends HttpServlet {
HttpServletResponse response)
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String jobCategory = request.getParameter("jobCat");
  System.out.println("Job category is: " + jobCategory);
 }
}
 but no output even print not executed .. i think it means that servlet is not called

Comment: Do you get `404 -page not found ` , pls update your question with the html code you are trying

Comment: there is one file scheduleMeet.jsp and the dopost method is in SSV.java

Comment: update your question with `scheduleMeet.jsp` to get clear anwer

Comment: Sorry .. can u guide me now?

Comment: edit your ques and show your scheduleMeet.jsp and the SSV.java